# converting png to movies with R via ffmpeg

Tags: r, ffmpeg

I want to convert a series of *.png files to a movie with R and have installed ffmpeg in the root directory.  I think the installation has been successful because if I type

```
     ffmpeg -version
```

in terminal I get all of the version information etc., etc.

I have my *.png files saved in the wd and in R I say

```
    imgs <- list.files(pattern="*.png")
        saveVideo({
        for(img in imgs){
          im <- magick::image_read(img)
          plot(as.raster(im))
        }
      })
```

I get an error message that "the command ""ffmpeg"" is not available in your system. Please install FFmpeg". Is there something I need to do to get R and ffmpeg to talk to each other? Again, from terminal, ffmpeg is in the directory and it looks like it installed.

thanks

Comment: Did you restart R after installing `ffmpeg`? Does `Sys.which("ffmpeg")` return a path inside R? What OS are you using?

Comment: I restarted R and that did it.  Thanks.